# Regex trim excess characters

Tags: regex

Im using the regex `([A-Za-z])\\1+", "$1` to trim excess characters from any given string.

However here's the problem. If there is a word with double-letters like so:

```
success
```

It turns into:

```
suces
```

How can I fix this regex to allow 2 characters, but trim past that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll( "(([A-Za-z])\\2)\\2+", "$1");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV2rJ1/1)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fix this regex to allow 2 characters, but trim past that?

Use this regex,

```
([A-Za-z])\\1{2,}
```

Then replace the match by `$1` . `\1{2,}` matches the captured character two or more times.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works for me:

```
/^\s+|\s+$/g
```

Explanation:

- `^\s+` := check beginning of the string for any number of white space characters in a row
- `\s+$` := check the end of the string for any number of white space characters in a row
- `|` := "OR", check if either of the patterns,`^\s+` or `\s+$`are present
- `g` := search for multiple matches (ie: some strings might have spaces at both start and end)